# Choosing an element of $W_x$ in a computable way

Tags: computability

If $W_x$ denotes the domain of the program with number $x$, the question is:

> Is there a partial computable function $f$ such that if $W_x$ is not empty then $f(x)\in W_x$, and otherwise, $f(x)$ is undefined?

My attempt is to take $f(x)=x$ if $x\in W_x$ and otherwise, $f$ is undefined. But I don't know how to deal with the non-empty condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer does not work, because there could be some element of $W_x$ other than $x$.

This is indeed possible. I will give an informal description of how to do this.

```
n <- 0;
Loop {
   n <- n + 1;
   For each i such that 1 <= i <= n do {
      Attempt to run algorithm x on input i for n steps;
      If this results in x halting on input i, halt and output i.
   }
}
```

If $x$ halts on some input $i$, then this algorithm will eventually halt on or before the iteration where $n = i$. And if this algorithm halts and returns $i$, then it must be the case that $x$ halts on input $i$.

Comment: +1. Note to the OP that this answer doesn't just use the *set* $W_x$ but the *specific enumeration* of $W_x$ corresponding to the *index* $x$; that is, we can have $W_x=W_y$ but $f(x)\not=f(y)$. It's a good exercise to show that this is unavoidable: there is no computable partial function $h$ such that $(i)$ if $W_x\not=\emptyset$ then $h(x)$ is defined and in $W_x$ and $(ii)$ if $W_x=W_y$ then $h(x)\simeq h(y)$ (where "$\simeq$" means "either both sides are undefined, or both sides are defined and equal to each other").